# Tensorflow Estimator Predict for Deep Wide Model

Tags: python, tensorflow

Can someone give a clear example on how to call `prediction` on `tf.estimator`?

Two things are unclear to me

1. When the input file doesn't have the label column, how to adjust the `input_fn`
2. How to export the predicted results

I am working on deep_wide model.

Comment: This [article](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-tensorflow-datasets.html) should be a great read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer myself and hope this can help someone with similar questions

For question 1, yes we need to construct a new input function and most likely it will have different number of columns as your input csv, since we are removing the label column

```
def parse_csv(value):
    print('Parsing', data_file)
    columns = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=_PREDICT_COLUMNS_DEFAULTS)
    features = dict(zip(_PREDICT_COLUMNS, columns))

    return features

def predict_input_fn(data_file):
    assert tf.gfile.Exists(data_file), ('%s not found. Please make sure the path is correct.' % data_file)

    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(data_file)
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_csv, num_parallel_calls=5)
    dataset = dataset.batch(1) # this is very important to keep the rank right
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    features = iterator.get_next()
    return features
```

Then for question 2, you use the new `input_fn` to predict the results

```
def predict(model):
    start_from_id = 892
    test_csv = []

    results = model.predict(
        input_fn=lambda: predict_input_fn(data_file='test.csv')
    )

    # for result in results:
    #     print 'result: {}'.format(result)
```